Why do people call Kamala Harris by just her first name sometimes?
I've heard and seen a lot of people call Kamala Harris by her first name, Kamala, both in conversations and on social media. Generally people refer to public figures by their last names or both first and last names. For example, people say Trump, Biden, Waltz, and Vance (or use both names). No one would call them Donald, Joe, Tim, or JD.
So, why is this different for Kamala Harris?

Partly sexism, partly choices made by her own campaign messaging. But you've never heard people say "The Donald" or "Uncle Joe"?

Never heard the first. I have heard the second, yes, and it's much more rare though. but certainly no one would say "Joe" @Obie2.0

His supporters call him "The Donald" all the time, enough that they named a major community after it. You may understandably not have spent enough time among them to hear it, though.

I've heard Trump called "Donald" quite a bit. In UK politics, I've also heard Johnson simply called "Boris" and Sunak "Rishi", as well as Starmer "Keir". It's not unique by any means.

(briefly noting that Boris is not actually Johnson's first name)

I would say also that Kamala is such an atypical name that it is a better identifier than "Harris". If you go for brevity at the expense of formality, it is not a strange choice.

@SJuan76 I'd say Harris is probably as rare or rarer than kamala

@Starship: The US Census, says Harris was the 25th most common surname in 2010.  On the other hand, SSA.gov says Kamala isn't even in the top 200 names for the 2010s (nor the previous 3 decades).

@Brian I think Starship may have been speaking globally. forebears.io tells me that Kamala is the 947th most common given name in the world (almost a million people), and Harris is the 482nd most common surname (a little over a million). So _ Harris is still more common than Kamala _ , but not by much.

@Brian Maybe Starship is from India. Kamala is a popular girl's name there, I doubt Harris is a common surname.

I seem to recall Jeb Bush had quite a bit of campaign material branded "Jeb" (or "Jeb!"), but being the third person in your immediate family to run for President will do that.

@shoover: While that's very interesting, it has very little bearing on the US election, since campaigns are almost 100% directed toward voters, which means only US citizens.  And in that context, it's a strong and unambiguous identifier (there can't be more than a handful of politicians sharing the name in the whole US, and none at the national level where this race is taking place).

@Barmar Nah I'm not from India.

@user25730 also not their first names: Neville Chamberlain, Anthony Eden, Harold Macmillan, Harold Wilson, James Callaghan, Gordon Brown, Liz Truss.

I fail to see why this is not a question about a political personality as outlined by the help center. One could argue that it is opinion-based, but not out of scope. Voting to reopen.

Could have something to do with sharing a name with U.S. House Representative Harris.

Going back even further there was Honest Abe, and Nixon was known by appellations like Tricky Dicky. Reagan was often called Ronnie. You could also look at nicknames like Ike and initialisms like JFK.

Women in professional positions are across the board  twice as likely to be  referred to by their first names as men are . By both men and women.
https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC6048538/
Among other things  women’s last names  change when they get married. Therefore they frequently prefer to go by their first names.  The assumed default   when speaking about someone is frequently male, so using the woman’s first name can help clarify the person’s gender. Also in general women who don't know each other well are more likely to call each other by their first names than men who don't know each other well are.

"so using the woman’s first name can help clarify the person’s gender" It probably is a reason, but needed people to clarify the person's gender in this case? If I said candidate Trump instead of Donald, would people have had doubt about the gender of the person I'm referring to?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution In US politics, the necessity to include additional identifier information varies depending on worldview. But in general society gender clues are included in language anywhere a distinction is wanted. In the case of presidential candidates there are few women compared to men so a gender identifier is useful to many voters. Exceptions to the normal are typically what is emphasized over what is expected. Pointing out the lack of necessity towards Trump kinda highlights the exception that Kamala is and what it accomplishes here.

@DavidS Sure, just wanted to point out that different standards are applied. Whether that's seen as a good or bad thing or doesn't really matter in the end, is probably also varying per person.

I don’t see how that answers the "why". It just says that it’s common in a specific context. Not to mention that IMO that context doesn’t match Harris' case: there aren’t all that many presidential candidates that the kind of alleged confusion could arise.
